# avoid sub-modules and external packages in a module's namespace

Tags: python, module, namespaces, package

I'm writing a module to load a dataset.  I want to keep the interface/API as clean as possible - so I've made internal functions and variables hidden by prefacing their names with `__`.  Awesome.  My module, however, imports other packages (e.g. `numpy`) which still appear in my module's namespace, how can I avoid this?

i.e. my file looks something like:

Loader.py:

```
import numpy as np

__INTERNAL_VAR1 = True
EXTERNAL_VAR = True

def loadData():
    data = __INTERNAL_FUNC1()
    ...
    return data

def __INTERNAL_FUNC1():
    ...
    return data
```

and when I import my module `np` is exposed:

```
> import Loader
> Loader.[TAB]
  Loader.EXTERNAL_VAR   Loader.loadData   Loader.np
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the autocompletion you are using is correctly implemented, it should honour the `__all__` attribute of modules, if set.

Add a list of all names your module exports in that name:

```
__all__ = ['loadData', 'EXTERNAL_VAR']
```

The `__all__` variable is used to determine what names are imported if you use a `from modulename import *` wildcard import, as well as by the `help()` function when documenting your module.

There is no point in using double-underscore names as globals; it is a single underscore at the start that marks such names as 'internal' (by convention).

Comment: Hmm, cool!  Is this also a good way to hide my internal variables?  i.e. should I switch `__INTERNAL_VAR1` to `INTERNAL_VAR1` (since it's kind of annoying to have so many underscores everywhere in the source) but just omit it from `__all__` ?

Comment: @zhermes: yes, you can do that too.

Comment: doing `Help(Loader)` is only showing the things I put in `__all__`, similarly for `from Loader import *`, but my ipython (ipython-0.13.2_python-2.7.3) isn't 'honouring' this... and is still showing me all non-private variables

Comment: @zhermes: that's a configurable option in iPython, see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1571/. It is really a choice of the auto-completion developers wether or not they'll honour `__all__`, it is not a problem with Python itself, per se.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to create an `__init__.py` that contains a line that imports the functions and variables you need:

```
from Loader import EXTERNAL_VAR,loadData
```

This file should be placed inside a folder containing your module:

```
└── Loader
    ├── __init__.py
    └── Loader.py
```

Now when you import `Loader` you can access directly only `EXTERNAL_VAR` and `loadData` while all the other classes and modules are in `Loader.Loader.` 
This solution should be independent of your autocompletion system.

Comment: I prefer this. With this solution, `np` is not imported into `__init__.py` so `Loader` has no `np` attribute.  With the accepted answer, leaving `np` out of  `__all__` may eliminate it from displaying using tab completion, but  `Loader.np` is still in the namespace.